# How to deny access to a file in folder from url

Tags: c#

In my asp.net project I have a folder with email templates in htm format. 
Is it possible to deny access from direct url, e.g. http://server1/Resourses/ClientWelcomeTemplate.htm
Now by this link i see my template.

Thank you!

Comment: Which tech stack are you using? ASP.NET? .Net Core? Where is it hosted? In IIS? Apache?

Comment: You might be better off restricting said access from the hosting platform itself (IIS/Apache)

Comment: it`s hosted on IIS

Comment: Move it outside of the web root?